# How to unit test using Bottle framework

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, bottle

I have some API endpoints that I need to test and I'm not sure where to start. I'm using the Bottle framework and one of the methods I'm testing reads a parameter off the request. How do I simulate this in a test environment?

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a good solution yet?

Comment: I have actually. You can use webtest to do everything you need. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/

Answer (score 5):

Use [boddle](https://github.com/keredson/boddle) for unit testing if you want access to the normal bottle syntax.  Example:

```
import bottle, unittest
from boddle import boddle


@bottle.get('/woot')
def woot():
  return bottle.request.params['name']


class TestIt(unittest.TestCase):
  def testWoot(self):
    with boddle(params={'name':'derek'}):
      self.assertEqual(woot(), 'derek')


if __name__=='__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Bottle doesn't have some of the testing niceties that Flask has [(see here)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/).  But Bottle recommends using a WSGI Testing Tools along with a regular unit testing framework (http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html#functional-testing-bottle-applications).  You won't have access to bottle syntax or the parameters passed to templates, etc, but you won't have to actually run a separate server either.

Comment: see https://github.com/keredson/boddle for said bottle syntax niceties :)